# Magit Status - always split vertically

Tags: magit

Is there a configuration option in Magit that will force the "git status" window to always appear in a  vertical split?  I didn't see anything about that in the documentation, and Google was rather useless.

Comment: Are you aware of the general setting `split-window-preferred-function` and similar? These are in the manual, and control how Emacs splits windows for many different modes; this includes Magit, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 8):

You can control how Magit­ — and many other modes that open new windows — divide a window by customising the variables `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`, and, if you need more control, changing `split-window-preferred-function`. These are all documented in the Elisp reference, and see other questions here, e.g. [Algorithm on deciding splitting vertically or horizontally](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/algorithm-on-deciding-splitting-vertically-or-horizontally/17877#17877)

For a reason that I, and others, find puzzling, the default function prefers to split horizontally if possible, so in your case you might want to tweak the variables so that `split-height-threshold` is greater than your window's maximum height, and so that a window is never split horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

For me following solution worked out (Emacs 26.1): I customized
`split-height-threshold` to `80` and `split-width-threshold` to `160`.
It's from Spacemacs config. Since then my magit buffer always open as
vertical split, as well as diff buffers.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to configure the `split-width-threshold` to `0` and `split-height-threshold` to `nil` as `split-window-sensibly` recommends:

> In order to not split WINDOW vertically, set (or bind) the variable
>   `split-height-threshold` to nil.  Additionally, you can set
>   `split-width-threshold` to zero to make a horizontal split more likely
>   to occur.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28498/11377) recently. You could try this.

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             `(,(rx bos "*magit:")
               (display-buffer-reuse-window
                display-buffer-below-selected)
               (reusable-frames . visible)
               (side            . bottom)
               (window-height   . 0.4)))
```

But I don't use magit frequently and therefore I don't know if this would also open buffers in a vertical split, that you don't want to open that way.