# How to force 'Ctrl-X, Ctrl-B' to always split vertically?

Tags: window-splitting

Once upon a time, [Choose Window](http://www.keyxl.com/aaa8773/92/Emacs-emac-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm) (invoked by `C-x C-b`) used to always split the window vertically.

Starting from a certain Emacs version (I can't recall which one), that split is now either vertical or horizontal, depending on the containing windows **aspect ratio**.

Is there a way to force `C-x C-b` to always split vertically?

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17872/4068 for previous answers from bmag and Stefan for variables that modify emacs behaviour. Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/23659909/2911961 gives us "I can set `split-height-threshold` to `nil` to inhibit vertical split altogether" from Romain

Comment: The attached link is invalid.

Comment: That "Choose Window" label is odd. By default, as `C-h k C-x C-b` will tell you, "C-x C-b runs the command `list-buffers`". Even taking into account that it's paraphrasing the commands, "Choose Window" doesn't make sense as a description for `list-buffers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite that keybinding with a hack like that:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b")
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action ;; force window
                         '((display-buffer-reuse-window 
                            display-buffer-same-window)
                           (inhibit-same-window . nil))))
                    (split-window-horizontally) ;; split window
                    (other-window 1) ;; change it
                    (list-buffers))))
```

In general I prefer use `ibuffer` instead of `list-buffers`, but now is your call. Use whatever you think that is better :)

Comment: I put your solution in my .emacs but it now complains *"Symbol's function definition is void: split-window-right".* Is your solution version-specific?

Comment: Maybe is if your emacs version is too old. Emacs currently is on version 27, I use 25.3. You can find the source of this function here: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/bc511a64f6da9ab51acc7c8865e80c4a4cb655c2/lisp/window.el#L5238

Comment: You're right. I am still using version 23.2. I managed to copy the function to my `.emacs` and the horizontal splitting works perfectly. Vertical splitting works almost perfectly (when the vertical split occurs, the bottom window also splits horizontally).

Comment: P.S. I can neither upvote nor accept answers since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem at all, but I think you can accept answer yes. On my machine works perfectly the solution I attached here, probably the "almost" is something because the emacs version. Upgrade emacs is not a option for you use-case?

Comment: Change `split-window-right` to `split-window-horizontally`, which is the original name for that command (and it remains as an alias in current versions of Emacs, so it's not going to break if you update).

Answer (score 0):

[Credit - How to change the default split-screen direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997590/how-to-change-the-default-split-screen-direction.)

The code below worked for me.

```
$ cat ~/.emacs
;;
;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997590/how-to-change-the-default-split-screen-direction
;; C-x C-b
;; splits the window vertically
;;

;; Use (setq split-width-threshold nil) for vertical split.
;; Use (setq split-width-threshold 1 ) for horizontal split.
;; (setq split-width-threshold 1 )
(setq split-width-threshold nil)
```